# @import font VS HTML links for external CSS

Tags: css, fonts, cdn, google-cdn

I have a website which uses two fonts from the Google CDN.

The first is @imported from a Google CDN at the beginning of the main CSS file, like so:

```
// Start of file
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic);

html, body { height: 100%, width: 100%:
// rest of file
```

A second font is linked directly in HTML from a Google CDN, like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,700,600" />
```

Can any one explain the implication of each method for performance and why one would choose one over the other?

Comment: not quite: the question you linked to discusses the difference between linking and importing CSS files. I'm trying to determine the effects when importing fonts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

General answer here; in brief, [don't use import](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/).